# FileExists check in WSH script giving object expected error

Tags: wsh

Why am I getting a runtime error "Object expected" in - If (fs.FileExists(filename)) ?

```
  var filename = "d:\\list.txt";

  fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

  If (fs.FileExists(filename)) //i 'm getting a runtime error "Object expected" here
  {
    // Open the file 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `If` to `if`. JScript is a case-sensitive language.